# Handle data from added field in ModelForm via Create View

Tags: python, django

What I'm trying to do is something like this:

1) I've created model

```
class Example(models.Model):

     username = models.CharField(max_lenght=111)
     pass = models.CharField(max_lenght=111)
```

2)I've created form using ModelForm, and added one extra field

```
class ExampleForm(ModelForm):

    extra_field= form.CharField(max_length=333)

    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = ['username', 'pass']
```

3)I've created view to handle this form

```
class Registration(CreateView):
    """
    View handles user registration.
    """
    form_class = ExampleForm
    model = Example
    template_name = 'accounts/registration.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('accounts:registered')
```

Now what I would like to do is do some custom processing of extra_field. I figured out this should be done in save method of ExampleForm. For example:

```
 def save(self, commit=True):

        user = super(ExampleForm, self).save(commit=False)
        data = self.cleaned_data['extra_field']
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['pass'] + self.cleaned_data['extra_field'])

        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

But this doesn't work.
Is this the right way to handle this kind of situation, or there is better way?
Biggest problem is that this isn't my code, so I should only change ExampleForm.
Is there way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards,
Nikola

Comment: What doesnt work ? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Well, now I've tried it with extra_field= form.CharField(), and it works.
What I need is ImageField().
Registration view never return accounts:registered template, and never create user(example) in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in the `form_valid()` method of the `CreateView`.

```
class Registration(CreateView):
    """
    View handles user registration.
    """
    form_class = ExampleForm
    model = Example
    template_name = 'accounts/registration.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('accounts:registered')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        example = form.save(commit=False)
        example.extra_field = derive_data(form.cleaned_data)
        example.save()
        return super(Registration, self).form_valid(form)
```